# VIM: how to get the file path/directory of opened buffer and do something?

Tags: dictionary, vim, makefile, command

my scenario is: I'm using vim to open some .cpp files, for example

```
vim 1.cpp src/2.cpp root/src/3.cpp
```

Sometimes, I wish to rebuild 3.cpp so I have to use another window to

```
"rm root/src/3.o"
```

and inside vim, type

```
":make"
```

This works fine, NP. But I am looking for a .vimrc function/command that:

When I switch to buffer, e.g. "root/src/3.cpp" and press this command, vim will detect the directory of "root/src" and the file name without suffix "3", and automatically execute a command of "rm root/src/3.o".

In this case, I can casually switch to any buffer and re-trigger the build of this very file.

Note I don't wish to map gmake tool command like "make clean" because we use several different make utilities like scons, cmake, etc.

So how to write this function/command in .vimrc? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to write in bold and big font size in order to read the question. It's like you are screaming in my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:call system('rm '.expand('%:p:r'))` as @Kent said, or even simply `:!rm %:p:r`.

But I'm quite surprised you need to do that. Tools in charge of compilation chains usually understand dependencies (which ever the tool is), and you shouldn't need to remove the object file that often to need a mapping to do it for you.

PS: it's perfectly [possible (but I need to update the doc)](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/project/doc/cmake.md) to support CMake, or out-of-source compilation from vim. But indeed, with out-of-sources compilation, you wouldn't need to delete those files manually, a `:make clean` if `:make` already works.

Answer (score 2):

you can get `root/src/3` from `root/src/3.cpp` buffer by:

```
expand('%:p:r')
```

Then you are free to concatenate the `.o` to end, and build the command.